# ruby logger file behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i am using this script its working fine

```
require 'logger'

class Logging < Logger
    log = Logger.new "sam.txt"
    log.warn "samarth"
end
```

and output of log file is coming in this way

```
# Logfile created on Thu Sep 20 12:01:26 +0530 2012 by /
W, [2012-09-20T12:01:44.402915 #7553]  WARN -- : asasa
```

Now i want to make a class which inherit logger and i am using that script in all other but its producing some different output

```
require 'date'
require 'logger'

class Logging < Logger

    def initialize 
      @date = Time.now.strftime("20%y-%m-%d").to_s
      @time = Time.now.strftime("%X")
      @file_name = @date+"_"+@time+ " log.txt"
      @file_name_path = '/cmf/samnew/build/Logs/'+@file_name
    end

    def createfile
      $log1 = Logger.new(@file_name_path)
      return $log1 
    end

end
```

i am implementing this script in below script

```
require '/cmf/samnew/build/Controller/logging'


class Controller

    #Generating log file

    log = Logging.new
    log1 =  log.createfile
    log1.warn "samarth global"

end
```

and output is like

```
# Logfile created on Thu Sep 20 12:03:20 +0530 2012 by /
samarth global
```

So what is wrong in this code or what should i do to create output like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably one of the gems you load messes up the global formatting string.

Try this to define your wished format

```
def createfile 
  $log1 = Logger.new(@file_name_path) 
  $log1.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg| 
    "#{severity[0]}, [#{datetime} \##{$$}] #{severity} --> #{msg} \n"
  end
  $log1  
end
```